Do Azure Data Factory job clusters need Unity Catalog Permissions to access unity catalog tables in databricks? What permissions are needed?
I'm building out an ADF pipeline that calls a databricks notebook at one point. This notebook reads from Databricks Unity Catalog tables to generate some data and writes to to another Unity Catalog table. Interactive clusters require specific permissions to access this data and without permissions it's not possible to view it.
In the past I've not run into issues with job clusters because they did not use unity catalog tables, so cluster permissions were not needed
I'm a little confused on how this would apply to Job Clusters that are created at runtime. Are there parameters to the Databricks Linked Service I could utilize to grant access to those job clusters?
The other solution would be to have a single user cluster that is dedicated to the process I'm building, and that would be used whenever the ADF pipeline was called. That cluster already has those permissions so it wouldn't be an issue. However I've heard that this is inadvisable in a production environment
There isn't specific documentation I've been able to find that addresses this, but this scenario may be a little obscure.
My question can be summarized as: How can Azure Data Factory job clusters be granted permissions to read databricks Unity Catalog tables?
I've attempted to use a job cluster and the databricks notebook was called, but would fail when trying to read a unity catalog table.
I was able to temporarily get around the issue by using a interactive cluster instead

What is the error message you are getting while using job cluster?

The permissions are granted to the users, not to clusters. In this case the "user" is Data Factory, so the permissions should be granted to its identity. The identity has object id and application id. Application id is the one that should be used.
